# After unregistering, I get "class deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it"

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

I have some code which applies to a number of objects, registering my class as the KVO:

```
for (SPPanelManager *manager in self.panelManagers) {
    [manager addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dataFetchComplete" options:0 context:NULL];
    [manager fetchData];
}
```

Then when it observes a change, which happens on every of these objects, I un-register:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"dataFetchComplete"] && ((SPPanelManager *)object).dataFetchComplete) {
        [object removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dataFetchComplete"];

        //Other stuff
    }
}
```

Then when I leave the UIViewController later, I get these errors for each of the manager objects:

> An instance of class was deallocated while key value observers were
>   still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even
>   become mistakenly attached to some other object.

I'm not sure why it's giving me this error - these are the only 2 places that KVO is ever referenced so it's not another observer.

Comment: You need to remove the observers even if the `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` method is never called (or it is called and the `if` condition isn't met).

Comment: Removing them if the don't exist causes a crash. But also, that second method is always called.

Comment: You are running the addObserver: method in a for loop. Have you checked to make sure it isn't adding the observer twice? There is a separate method to remove observers under this scenario: removeObserver:forKeyPath:context:

Answer (score 2):

Your class(observer) is being deallocated during some activity. You must unregister it before it is deallocated or not is in further use. Use code below in `viewDidUnload:` or `dealloc:`

```
for (SPPanelManager *manager in self.panelManagers) {
    [manager removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dataFetchComplete" context:NULL];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to add or remove observers in `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`. KVO expects the list of observers for a given Tuple(`object`, `keyPath`, `context`) to remain the same across a notification for that combination. Even it it works "sometimes" the behavior is non-deterministic because the order in which observers are notified is not guaranteed (it probably uses a set-type data structure internally.)

The simplest way around this problem might look something like:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"dataFetchComplete"] && ((SPPanelManager *)object).dataFetchComplete) {
        CFRunLoopPerformBlock(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes, ^{
            [object removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dataFetchComplete"];
        });
    }
}
```

This will cause the observation to be removed at the next possible point in the run loop (barring custom run loop modes, which might delay its execution a bit, but usually won't be a problem). Also, you shouldn't need to worry about either `self` or `object` getting deallocated because they will be retained by the block closure until the block has executed and is, itself, releases.

As you've discovered, KVO isn't a particularly great API for one-shot notifications.

As to the initial error message, you'll need to remove the observation. You can probably get away with doing this in the observing object's `dealloc` but you should really avoid doing "real work" in `dealloc` and removing observations is arguably "real work." Unfortunately, there's not a standard teardown pattern in Cocoa, so you'd have to trigger the teardown yourself, perhaps when you segue out of the view controller, or something like that. Another answer suggested `viewDidUnload` but that is deprecated in iOS 6 and will never be called, so it's not a good approach any more.

Answer (score 0):

You've to simply dealloc your `GMS_MapView` Object and as well as remove the MapView Observer forkeypath.

```
(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [objGMS_MapView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myLocation"];

    //=>    Set map delegate to nil (to avoid:   mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:]: message sent to deallocated instance )
    objGMS_MapView.delegate = nil;
    objGMS_MapView = nil;
}
```